# Dialogflow disambiguation

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to Dialogflow and want to make a demo with sports results, stats, etc.
My problem is with disambiguation, for instance

> What was the result of Manchester against Liverpool?

`Manchester` could mean `M. United` or `M. City` so I have to ask the user which one is he referring to.
What is the quickest way to do this? Please note that there are a lot of intents (20+) that need this disambiguation so a one-off solution would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simplest way is to ask for the context. Simply ask "Do you mean the soccer club or the city?"

Comment: Yes, but the problem is how to preserve the contexts.
"Manchester" could appear in multiple cases, examples:
- What's the best scorer of Manchester?
 What was the result of Manchester against Liverpool?
Does Manchester have more goals than Chelsea? Etc, etc...
Handling disambiguation for all these cases is a pain. My question is if there's another way, when a certain entity is mentioned always ask to disambiguate preserving the current context.

Comment: There is so universal solution. What do you think why the Google Assistant itself cannot answer all questions? They have the same problem! You should focus on a special topic like soccer results or whatever. Then you have a clear focus and context. If it is still not clear try to guess it or ask for it e.g. with some kind of knowledge graph. Think about a voice app to buy goods, in your data base will be very likly no article called "Water" maybe something like Volvic 1,5L. That is a hard problem to solve. E.g. if no water is offered, you may look at softdrinks instead you get the point?

Comment: What I'm trying to disambiguate are two soccer clubs from the same city: Man. City and Man. United. The project is only for soccer results.

Comment: Oh sorry I was not aware that there are two teams. The list of soccer clubs with the same prefix should be short. Ask in those cases just for matches with equal prefixes. That should be easy with a medium effort.

Comment: Thanks anyway, @rekire. I'm trying to use a custom event (`which_manchester`) and trigger it using followupEventInput in the fullfillment routines but still no luck.

Comment: I would trigger the disambiguation from the server side, not within dialogflow

Comment: What I've done to solve this was to create two intents (`Club.ManCity` and `Club.ManUtd`) with the same context (`which_manchester`) and use it when needed in the fullfilment routines (using `outputContexts`) along with extra parameters to preserve the action, etc.
It's ugly but it works.